# Template Specification

Tags: c++

Is there a possibility to specialize the templates to abstract this behavior (specialize the type using a logical or) without
using another helper class.

To specialize when I pass int or char to the same class.

```
template<typename K>
struct test
{

};

template<>
struct test<int or char>
{

};
```

Thanks.

CB

Comment: I want to get something like logical or behavior while specifying the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C++11 type traits for this (or, if you don't have C++11 yet, use type traits from Boost):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename K, bool special = std::is_same<K, char>::value || std::is_same<K, int>::value>
struct A
{
  // general case
};

template <typename K>
srtuct A<K, true>
{
  //int-or-char case
};
```

Comment: Thanks Angew. This is exactly what I want. I have no idea why people just vote down when they do not know. :) :)

Comment: @cowboy To be honest, I was half guessing what you were after. The question was rather unclear in its original form.

Comment: yeah that is true. I could check them before post. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @cowboy: While SFINAE can be used in multiple contexts, it might end up making maintenance a bit harder... I would consider this in the greater scope of the project and who needs to maintain it. How easy will it be to maintain the code for the people involved?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, that is true, it can be confusing to maintain sometimes. However,  this was rather for knowledge than for an actual implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your question is too vague, but i think you talk about smth like this?

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    //...
}

template<B>
struct A
{
    //...
}
```

in this case you specify how should template struct behave its of templated of some specific type

Answer (score 0):

C++ supports partial specialization. The simplest way to solve your problem (I think this is your problem) is to partially specialize struct test for int or char, ala:

```
template <typename T> struct test
{
    // For arbitrary type T...
};

template <>
struct test<int>
{
    // definition for when T = int
};

template <>
struct test<char>
{
    // definition for when T = char
};
```

Comment: not actually. thanks. I want to know if I can get the logial or behavior while specializing the template. Or is it not possible as it is compile time specification.